# Removing utf-8 identifier (BOM) from Response Sent by WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, utf-8

I am creating a clone of the facebook Rest API in c#, I am testing it with the facebook PHP sdk. The problem I am having is that the responses sent by my net Rest Service contain utf-8 Bom in front of it and Facebook SDK is not able to parse the responses correctly.
Any ideas on how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you can specify a specific `Encoding` to your service, then you can use `new UTF8Encoding(false)` which is UTF-8 without BOM.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you are returning in your service, but if it is a string like mine (I was returning a json), you can simply return a Message object instead with the string in it (from System.ServiceModel.Channels - google it) and then at the end of your service method implementation just do this:

```
Encoding utf8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false); //false == no BOM
return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(stringWithContent, "application/json;charset=utf-8", utf8);
```

Answer (score -1):

[The Wikipedia UTF-8 article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8#Byte_order_mark) suggests that the pretend-BOM that Windows applications frequently prepend to the actual content is three bytes long. Can you simply not send the first three bytes of your generated content?